# Add tags after envelope creation but before generating the recipient view

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I need to create an envelope by defining the recipients and the document. After creating the envelope, I then need to manually add the tags. After adding the tags, I want to generate a recipient URL for this particular envelope ID. Is this possible?

I do not want to send the envelope but edit it by adding tags. I will generate a recipient view separately. Currently, I am unable to find a way to add the tags after envelope creation and before sending.

I tried to create the envelope with status: `created` and then generated the `correction` view. On opening the URL, it said cannot find the envelope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an envelope and if you want to show Send Button to the sender then use createSender View https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/

and if you dont want to show Send button then create envelope with sent status and use createCorrect View https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createCorrect/

And if you don't want recipient to receive any email then make that recipient an embedded recipient by adding clientUserId, once clientUserId is added then that recipient will not receive an email. To get recipient View, you should use below call https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/

Comment: Is there a way to generate embedded link just using envelopeId? I need to generate a link when I only have the envelopeId. Could you please help answer this?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Which embedded link you want? recipientView or something else?

Comment: I need recipient view but all I have is an envelope id

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Create:EnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/) api to add tabs to a draft envelope.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

{
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
      "anchorString": "Sign",
      "anchorMatchWholeWord": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using a UI?

Comment: I am looking for a way to add tags using an interface just like what we have in `correction-view` or the `sender-view`

Comment: Could we have a conversation here at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154263/migrated-from-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-46183345-add-tags-after-envelop